# How to remove subdirectories and replace file extensions with a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following is my directory structure

```
Root (example.com)/
                   index.htm
                   contact.htm
                   privacy.htm
                   disclaimer.htm
                   cat/
                       play/
                            fun.htm
                       rest/
                            sleep.htm
```

I managed to remove the file extension and add a trailing slash with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R,L]
```

But I also want to make it in such a way that when people go to `www.example.com/fun/` they're able to access `www.example.com/cat/play/fun.htm` without redirecting, which means, in the address bar it still shows `www.example.com/fun/`.

I know I can use the direct approach like:

```
RewriteRule ^fun/$ /cat/play/fun.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^sleep/$ /cat/rest/sleep.htm [L]
```

But I'll be adding more files to these 2 subdirectories (/cat/play/ and /cat/rest/), so I was wondering if there's a single rewrite rule to perform the rewrites for these files instead of having to enter 100 rewrite rules for 100 files under those 2 subdirectories. Please enlighten.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^fun/?$ play/fun.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^sleep/?$ rest/sleep.htm [L]
```

They cannot be moved to one rule, so they should be used with separate rules for each URL.

Comment: Hi Volodymyr, thanks for the input. That was exactly what I thought. You might want to take a look at my edited questions as I've added a subdirectory called 'cat' and see if you're able to help me with this. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: I think that it will be in indeterminate state. You won't know exactly in which directory you want to search that file. Is it possible to remove play or rest folder, to leave only one?

Comment: Hi Volodymyr, you're probably right to say that it will be in indeterminate state. I raised this up because I've seen a few websites doing something like this. So, it could be them doing the direct way, maybe. Anyway, I really appreciate your response. Thank you very much. Enjoy your weekend ;)